# How To Use Two Different XML-Configuration-Files For Log4J

Tags: java, log4j

I have two XML-configurations files. One for my Java Jersey WebService and one for my Data Access Object (=DAO; MySQL-DB via JDBC). When I run my application, the logs are seperated in two diffrent folders, but the log-file is identical to each other.

How can I avoid that?

XML-Configuration for DAO:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="true"
  xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

    <!-- CONSOLE -->    
    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" 
            value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <!-- ERROR LOG INTO FILE -->
    <appender name="dberr" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="append" value="true" />
        <param name="maxFileSize" value="5MB" />
        <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="5" />
        <param name="file" value="logs/database/errlog.log" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" 
            value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
        </layout>
        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
            <param name="LevelMin" value="ERROR" />
            <param name="LevelMax" value="FATAL" />
        </filter>
    </appender>

    <!-- STANDARD LOG INTO FILE -->
    <appender name="dbstd" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="append" value="true" />
        <param name="maxFileSize" value="5MB" />
        <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="5" />
        <param name="file" value="logs/database/std.log" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" 
            value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
        </layout>
        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
            <param name="LevelMin" value="INFO" />
            <param name="LevelMax" value="WARN" />
        </filter>
    </appender>

    <!-- DEBUG LOG INTO FILE -->
    <appender name="dbdebug" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="append" value="true" />
        <param name="maxFileSize" value="5MB" />
        <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="5" />
        <param name="file" value="logs/database/debug.log" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" 
            value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
        </layout>
        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
            <param name="LevelMin" value="DEBUG" />
            <param name="LevelMax" value="DEBUG" />
        </filter>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="dberr" />
        <appender-ref ref="dbstd" />
        <appender-ref ref="dbdebug" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

XML-Configuration For WebService:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="true"
  xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

    <!-- CONSOLE -->    
    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" 
            value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <!-- ERROR LOG INTO FILE -->
    <appender name="wserr" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="append" value="true" />
        <param name="maxFileSize" value="5MB" />
        <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="5" />
        <param name="file" value="logs/webservice/errlog.log" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" 
            value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
        </layout>
        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
            <param name="LevelMin" value="ERROR" />
            <param name="LevelMax" value="FATAL" />
        </filter>
    </appender>

    <!-- STANDARD LOG INTO FILE -->
    <appender name="wsstd" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="append" value="true" />
        <param name="maxFileSize" value="5MB" />
        <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="5" />
        <param name="file" value="logs/webservice/std.log" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" 
            value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
        </layout>
        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
            <param name="LevelMin" value="INFO" />
            <param name="LevelMax" value="WARN" />
        </filter>
    </appender>

    <!-- DEBUG LOG INTO FILE -->
    <appender name="wsdebug" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="append" value="true" />
        <param name="maxFileSize" value="5MB" />
        <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="5" />
        <param name="file" value="logs/webservice/debug.log" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" 
            value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
        </layout>
        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
            <param name="LevelMin" value="DEBUG" />
            <param name="LevelMax" value="DEBUG" />
        </filter>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="wserr" />
        <appender-ref ref="wsstd" />
        <appender-ref ref="wsdebug" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

And this is how I call Log4J:

```
Logger log  =   Logger.getLogger(DAO.class);
DOMConfigurator.configure("C:\file\path\to\config.xml");
```

I want log-files with logs olny from the DAO in a folder and the equivalent for the WebService. What is my bad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I merged the two files into one single XML-file. What i needed to do is this:

```
    <logger name="webservice_container">
        <appender-ref ref="wserr" />
        <appender-ref ref="wsstd" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="db_container">
        <appender-ref ref="dberr" />
        <appender-ref ref="dbstd" />
    </logger>

    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
    </root>
```

Now I have one single file in that I have all configurations for Log4J that loggs in 2 different folders and 4 different files.